# Diálogos na Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

estou tentando criar uma caixa de diálogo para um projeto de TCC, mas não está funcionando, não consigo encontrar o erro que está impedindo o funcionamento

Prints do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é que quando o diamante ficasse perto do círculo a caixa aparecesse, mas não está funcionando. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Por favor

Answer (score 1):

Verificando teu código só exibistes os códigos referente a teu ***BoxDialog***, tu precisa de um gatilho para que seja disparado teu método de exibição da Dialog, primeiramente no teu *BoxCollider2D*, clique no checkbox de *Is Trigger*, após isso é possível fazer de maneira simples o check utilizando um método da própria biblioteca do *MonoBehaviour* chamada ***OnTriggerEnter()*** ou ***OnTriggerStay()*** para que seja exibido teu Dialog, ficaria parecido com este trecho abaixo:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CheckCollisionToShowDialog : MonoBehaviour
    {
          [SerializeField] private GameObject dialog;

          void Start() {

              dialog.SetActive(true);
          }

          void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

              //Como só tem um objeto para colidir basta colocar
              //abaixo o trecho de código que fará a exebição da
              //tua dialog, caso tenham vários e houver a 
              //necessidade de check de name ou tag, basta colocar
              //um if checando o nome/tag, conforme exemplo abaixo:

              if (other.gameObject.tag == "minha tag") {
                  dialog.SetActive(true);
              }
          }
      }
```

Este acima código deve estar em algum dos dois objetos que ocorrerão a colisão, lembrando de utilizar o RigedBody nos corpos de colisão e também que ambos tenham o collider2D em trigger.

Uma outra solução para tua dúvida era checar a posição de ambos os corpos, dentro do WorldSpace da tua Scene. Desta maneira tu não precisaria trabalhar com nada de física, somente com a referente da posição que queres chegar, ou seja, o Transform final.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Gabriel.

Fale pra gente qual está sendo o comportamento. Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Em qual momento não está ocorrendo o comportamento esperado?

Comment: Não, ele simplesmente não parece nada, a tela continua preta e a caixa não aparece

Comment: Então coloque Debug.Log em pontos específicos do seu código para ver onde ele está parando. Comece pelo método Inicializa para ver se realmente está sendo chamado. Se não, coloca no chamador dele. Opcionalmente vc pode utilizar o depurador do Visual Studio. Também pense na hipótese de uma má configuração do trigger, no inspector.